# jQuery child of clicked element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I've got a list of links which have a click event attached to them, I need to get the ID from the child A link. So in the example below if I clicked the first list element I'd need google retuned.

I've tried `'$this a'` but can't quite work out the syntax.

```
$("ul li").click(function(event){
  $("input").val($(this).html());             
});
```

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com" id="google">Google</a>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I don't see the sample HTML but

```
$(this).find('a:first').attr('id')
```

would do it (fix *a:first* selector if it's not what you meant)

**this** refer to the element that fired your event

Comment: can I propose: jQuery(this).find('a:first').attr('id') ? I just run on a conflict in a project with prototype.

Answer (score 5):

To make your code a little neater, lets bind triggers with functions like so: 
(i suggest you give your UL an ID so it is specific to only elements within that UL)

```
$('ul li').bind('click', getAnchorId);
```

The function that is called (getAnchorId) gets the ID attribute of the children element (a) of the clicked element (ul li) and applies it to a variable (anchorId), and to show its getting the correct info I put the result in an alert.

```
function getAnchorId() {
    var anchorId = $(this).children('a').attr('id');
    alert(anchorId);
}
```

Now u can do what ever u wish with that variable :)

hope this helps :)

Comment: That is highly subjective, I personally prefer to use an anonymous function, especially since this is so specific.

Comment: agreed, and using bind is just extra key press effort instead of using .click.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`children`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/children) method:

```
$(this).children('a').eq(0).attr('id');
```

I'm not sure about the syntax, but something like this should work.

Comment: using the array indexer gives you a dom object back therefore the .attr method would not exist and error. U need $(this).children('a')[0].id or $(this).children('a').get(0).id or $(this).children('a').attr('id');

Comment: Are you sure it returns a DOM object? Either way, I said I wasn't sure, I'll test it sometime and correct it if it's wrong.

Comment: I fixed it by using `.eq(int)` which returns the jQuery element at the specified index.