# Get id of a checkbox inside a div jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I'm trying to get the id and the status(checked or not) of a checkbox inside a clicked div.

```
<div class="ui toggle checkbox toggle_stat">
<input id="1" type="checkbox" ></input>
<label>Assesed</label>
</div>

<div class="ui toggle checkbox toggle_stat">
<input id="2" type="checkbox" ></input>
<label>Assesed</label>
</div>

<div class="ui toggle checkbox toggle_stat">
<input id="3" type="checkbox" ></input>
<label>Assesed</label>
</div>
```

then i have this script:

```
$(".toggle_stat").click(function() {
```

here is the part where i'm stuck:

```
var id = //code here for getting the id of the checkbox
var isChecked =  //code here for getting the status of the checkbox
```

i already tried just using the $(":checkbox") but it's not working, i'm using a third party kitchensink.

```
 $.ajax({
    url: 'url',
    type: 'post',
    data: {id: id, checked: isChecked},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
    },
    error: function() {
    }});
        });
```

i would really appreciate guys a help. thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery child of clicked element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359393/jquery-child-of-clicked-element)

Comment: Don't bother guys, I already figured it out. I use:
    var id =  $(this).children(":checkbox").prop("id");
    var isChecked =  $(this).children(":checkbox").prop("checked");

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:checkbox` selector and then check the `id` and `checked` properties of the DOM element like so:

```
var id = $(this).find(":checkbox")[0].id;
var isChecked = $(this).find(":checkbox")[0].checked;
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jwnace/aL06s99s/