# how can i get particular div text from selected li

Tags: jquery, html

I have created multiple ul and I want particular div value from particular li

I have tried to make a function for that but it is not working

```js
$(".answer-list li").click(function() {
 $(this).addClass('active');
 BusinessLogic();
});

function BusinessLogic(){
   var selText = $('.answer-list li .active div p').text();
   alert(selText);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="answer-list" id="answer_list1">
  <li>
   <a tabindex="1" id="question1">
    <span class="letter-option">A.</span>
    <div>
     <p>Plan risk management</p>
    </div>
   </a>
  </li>
  <li class="active">
   <a tabindex="2" id="question1">
    <span class="letter-option">B.</span>
    <div>
     <p>Identify risks</p>
    </div>
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a tabindex="3" id="question1">
    <span class="letter-option">C.</span>
    <div>
     <p>Plan risk responses</p>
    </div>
   </a>
  
  </li><li>
   <a tabindex="4" id="question1">
    <span class="letter-option">D.</span>
    <div>
     <p>Perform qualitative risk analysis</p>
    </div>
   </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and I want selected li div value but it shows me blank

can anybody help me with this?

Comment: where is your script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery child of clicked element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359393/jquery-child-of-clicked-element)

Comment: pass this into your function? Also your selector is wrong - it is `li.active` not `li .active`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this to get the innerhtml of div tag.

```js
$(".answer-list li").click(function() {
 $('li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
 BusinessLogic();
});

function BusinessLogic(){
   var selText = $('.answer-list li.active div p').text();
   console.log(selText);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="answer-list" id="answer_list1">
        <li>
            <a tabindex="1" id="question1">
                <span class="letter-option">A.</span>
                <div>
                    <p>Plan risk management</p>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
            <a tabindex="2" id="question1">
                <span class="letter-option">B.</span>
                <div>
                    <p>Identify risks</p>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a tabindex="3" id="question1">
                <span class="letter-option">C.</span>
                <div>
                    <p>Plan risk responses</p>
                </div>
            </a>

        </li><li>
            <a tabindex="4" id="question1">
                <span class="letter-option">D.</span>
                <div>
                    <p>Perform qualitative risk analysis</p>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove active `Class` on li `click` event & remove space `.answer-list li.active`

```
$(".answer-list li").click(function() {
      $('.answer-list li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        BusinessLogic();
    });

    function BusinessLogic(){
       var selText = $('.answer-list li.active div p').text();
       alert(selText);
    }
```

```js
$(".answer-list li").click(function() {
  $('.answer-list li').removeClass('active');
 $(this).addClass('active');
 BusinessLogic();
});

function BusinessLogic(){
   var selText = $('.answer-list li.active div p').text();
   alert(selText);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="answer-list" id="answer_list1">
  <li>
   <a tabindex="1" id="question1">
    <span class="letter-option">A.</span>
    <div>
     <p>Plan risk management</p>
    </div>
   </a>
  </li>
  <li class="active">
   <a tabindex="2" id="question1">
    <span class="letter-option">B.</span>
    <div>
     <p>Identify risks</p>
    </div>
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a tabindex="3" id="question1">
    <span class="letter-option">C.</span>
    <div>
     <p>Plan risk responses</p>
    </div>
   </a>
  
  </li><li>
   <a tabindex="4" id="question1">
    <span class="letter-option">D.</span>
    <div>
     <p>Perform qualitative risk analysis</p>
    </div>
   </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```