# Chained reference to child element not working JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, parent-child

I am certain I am missing something basic, but I've been googling/trying things for the past hour and haven't made any progress.

Very simple: I want to show/hide a child element when the parent is clicked (using the css `visibility` attribute). Here is my code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div onclick="test()">
    <h2 class="t"> HI THERE</h2>
</div>

<script>
    function test() {
        var t = $(this).children('.t'); //THIS RETURNS [OBJECT OBJECT]
        alert(t.attr('class')); //THIS IS "undefined"
        t.css('visibility','hidden'); //THIS DOES NOT WORK
        // $('.t').css('visibility','hidden'); //THIS WORKS
    };
</script>
```

I have tried `.find()` `.children()`  and `.siblings()`. A good stack overflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359393/jquery-child-of-clicked-element) that should answer my question did not - I tried every answer/comment. I have also tried to find other ways of referencing this element, but it needs to be from the parent that has been clicked (there are too many elements in the "t" class to reference by id). But, it can be referenced by tag name (the parent to-be-clicked only has one child).

All help is very very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `this` is used in this context (in a function), it represents a global `window` object.

Change your function to

```
function test(element) {
    var t = $(element).children('.t'); 
    //other calls
}
```

...and in your `onclick`, send `this` as the parameter:

```
<div onclick="test(this)">...</div>
```